# Vue 3.4 same-name shorthand vs-code support

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, syntax-error, syntax-highlighting

I recently upgaraded my Vue 3 project to Vue 3.4. When I tried to use same-name shorthand, even though it was working fine, vs-code is highlighting it as an error, I am using volar. Is there any way to make vs-code understand this new Vue 3 syntax?

[image]

> **UPDATE**
>
> This issue is fixed now https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/pull/3831

Comment: i have the same problem, i guess we should wait for volar to update, meanwhile i just ignore it

Comment: Please share all information as text not as image

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Volar doesn't support it yet, there's an issue opened, you could vote:

https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/3830

Comment: @afollestad a github issue is never deleted, just closed